# Node.js writes unreadable text to console

Tags: node.js, windows, stdout

Using Node.js, these lines of code are printing unreadable text to my Windows console. How do I make it write readable ones? My problem is I need to print what is in a `Buffer` to stdout without a newline after each write.

```
process.stdout.write(new Buffer('05', 'hex').toString(encoding='ascii'));
process.stdout.write(new Buffer('05', 'hex').toString(encoding='utf8'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
process.stdout.write(new Buffer('05', 'hex').toString('hex'));
```

It's odd that the default encoding for `toString` is 'utf8'. It should inherit the encoding of the `Buffer` provided.